# Authenticate for Google Cloud PubSub using parameters from a config file in c#.net

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am following [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/api/QuickStart/Program.cs) sample in attempt to publish messages in PubSub from a c#.net app on a windows server. As expected it throws auth exception on:

```
PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.Create();
```

Most of my code base connects to GCS and BigQuery using their respective services, sample below:

```
private StorageService GetStorageService()
    {
      X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

      ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                  Scopes = new[] { StorageService.Scope.DevstorageFullControl }
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));

      return new StorageService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = projectNumber,
      });

    }
```

I just pass certificateFile, serviceAccountEmail from a config file as parameters. Is there anyway to Auth similarly for PubSub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you're looking in the right repo for samples.  I notice the QuickStart directory is missing a README.md.  I'll add one shortly.

To get this line of code to work:

```
PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.Create();
```

Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of a json service account credentials file.  Details are in step 3 of the root README:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/README.md

If your environment requires you to manually specify the path to a credential file, the code looks like this:

```
        GoogleCredential googleCredential = null;
        using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream)
                .CreateScoped(PublisherClient.DefaultScopes);
        }
        Channel channel = new Channel(PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, 
            PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port, 
            googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
        PublisherClient publisher = PublisherClient.Create(channel);
```

I reported issue https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1398 to make this common task simpler.

Comment: `PublisherClient.Create` has no overload for `GoogleCredential` Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential' to 'Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ServiceEndpoint'

Comment: Indeed.  I reported this issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/1398.